# Typo3: Error in ClassAliasLoader after installation/activation of an extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

we run a TYPO3 8.7.24 in composer mode and t3kit.
(further information: Apache 2.4.35, PHP 7.1.23, MySQL 5.6.41, FreeBSD 11.2)

We use several extensions and the system works fine. The Problems started as we wanted to install a new extension: "typo3-ter/frp-form-answers". So I added it in the composer.json:

```
"require": {
  "t3kit/theme-t3kit": "~2.8.0", 
  "typo3-ter/url-forwarding": "1.2.0",
  "pixelant/dashboard": "~8.0.0", 
  "kaystrobach/dyncss": "dev-master as 0.8.0", 
  "typo3-ter/frp-form-answers" : "~1.2" 
},
```

and performed "composer install". No errors, all looks fine. After that, I activated the extension via Typo3 Backend. After that, we server only returns a blank page / empty response. I checked apache error log and found nothing. The PHP error log only contains a warning:

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /xxxxxxxxxxx/cms/vendor/typo3/class-alias-loader/src/ClassAliasLoader.php on line 170

which occurs in the following method:

```
/**
 * Adds an alias map and merges it with already available map
 *
 * @param array $aliasMap
 */
public function addAliasMap(array $aliasMap)
{
    foreach ($aliasMap['aliasToClassNameMapping'] as $alias => $originalClassName) {
        $lowerCaseAlias = strtolower($alias);
        $this->aliasMap['aliasToClassNameMapping'][$lowerCaseAlias] = $originalClassName;
        $this->aliasMap['classNameToAliasMapping'][$originalClassName][$lowerCaseAlias] = $lowerCaseAlias;
    }
}
```

So I performed "composer dump-autoload" but without any effect. I tried to google that problem, but the most common solution was that last composer command.

So, I am out of sources for new solutions and have no real error in the logs. Has anyone else struggled with that problem?

I do not think it is problem with that specific extension. The same problems occur if I try to install the extension "typo3-formlog".

A other solution I found was:

> Try logging into your install tool. Under "important actions" you will find a section "Dump Autoload Information".

but that options do not exists in our install tool...

EDIT: The option "Check for broken extensions" in the install tool flags the new installed extension as broken.

Comment: What http code do you get on that empty page?

Comment: I also noticed that you added the dependency to composer.json and ran composer install. You should either add the dependency using composer require or run composer update after changing the composer.json file

Comment: "composer require" does the same as i do manually. And "composer update" was used. I tried again using "composer require" but with the same effect.

Comment: Chrome shows me no Repsonse Code. It looks like https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-err-empty-response-on-google-chrome/ and the Network tabs shows only "failed" instead of a http repsonse code.

Comment: You wrote you did `composer install` before which replicates the state of your composer.lock file even after you changed the composer.json file. Do you actually get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE or something else? Failed status in the network tab sounds suspicious, are you sure the Webserver is running, you have the correct url and port as well as the correct protocol (http or https on the correct port)

Comment: Yes. All works fine till the moment i activate the extension and. The moment i deactive the extension the page works again. Any problems with the webserver would be logged in apache error log. The log is empty. The "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" is common in typo3. During my researtch i found a lot of scenarios for that response.
I solved the problem. I switched to another extension :)